# How to reserve/save the last visited page in react-table v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v6

Hope everyone doing well!
Is there any way to send the user back to the last visited page in react-table v6, to elaborate more, the main table has a button in each row that sends the user to another page, but I want the user when he/she returns back to the main page to get the last visited page!

edited: I am using a class-based component in the whole project.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useHistory()` hook of React Router.

For more info, visit here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Comment: thanks, but I am using a class-based component so I am not sure if hooks can be used, I stored the last value in the redux store but the state object for react-table seems that it has its own values!